# Is it possible to refer to an entire column by its number in an Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently I am trying to set up a dynamic range using this formula structure:

```
=OFFSET($A$2,,,COUNTA($A:$A)-1)
```

I then modified the formula to find a keyword in the header row:

```
=OFFSET($A$2,,MATCH("THIS",$1:$1,0),COUNTA($A:$A)-1)
```

My issue is the COUNTA statement at this point.  I want to type something like `COUNTA(COLUMN(MATCH("THIS",$1:$1,0)))` but it doesn't appear to be this simple.

Instead my workaround is something to the effect of:

```
COUNTA(INDIRECT(LEFT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("THIS",$1:$1,0)),2)&":"&LEFT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("THIS",$1:$1,0)),2)))-1
```

The entire formula becomes rather long and cumbersome, and I have a feeling that I might be missing something to simplify it.  Is there an easier way to do this that would be similar to simply evaluating to `COUNTA(Column(10))` or is my approach the most efficient method?

Answer (score 1):

Try this definition

`=OFFSET($A$2,,MATCH("THIS",$1:$1,0)-1,COUNTA(OFFSET($A:$A,,MATCH("THIS",$1:$1,0)-1))-1)`

The second `OFFSET` gets the whole column